# Detect when Today Widget "Show More" is tapped or is expanded?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, today-extension

Is it possible to detect when the Today widget is expanded/contracted or 'Show More' button is tapped in Objective C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no way to detect whether the `Show More` button has been tapped in `Today Extension`.**

What you can do is determine if it's open with checking frame height.

You can add a boolean and set it in :

```
- (void)widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:(NCWidgetDisplayMode)activeDisplayMode withMaximumSize:(CGSize)maxSize {
    if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayModeCompact) {
        //non expanded
    } else {
        //expanded
    }
}
```

You can also have a layout that doesn't need to know if it's opened or closed, that's what most apps do.

Hope this helps :)